# How to Mock postgresql (pg) in node.js using Jasmine or third party lib?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jasmine, node-postgres

I have a method that queries a postgres database (node-postgres lib) and retrieves data from it and maps it into flat array.

```
export const getActiveUsersLast7DaysForProject = async (projectId: string): Promise<User[]> => {
  let userIds: string[] = [];
  const client = new PG.Client(config.encryptedCredentials); // prod only
  await client.connect();

  await client
    .query(
      '
      SELECT user_id FROM my_db.users_active ua
      WHERE ua.project_id='12345'
      GROUP BY user_id'
    )
    .then(
      (res: any) => (userIds = res.rows.flatMap((user: any) => user.user_id))
    )
    .catch((e: Error) => console.error(e.stack));

  return userIds;
};
```

How can I test it? Currently tests fail when it tries to connect to the db locally (as expected since credentials are not for localhost). Can I stub/mock the `query()` to return some test query result?

Alternatively, how to intercept the call to real db and use a mock one, for example with `pg-mem`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spyOn()` to mock `PG.Client` class and use `jasmine.createSpyObj()` to create spy obj for the instance of the `PG.Client` class.

Note: that testing by mock query results does not guarantee that your SQL statements are correct, only the application code is tested.

This is unit testing, stub side-effect I/O operations.

`index.ts`:

```
import PG from 'pg';

const config = {
  encryptedCredentials: {
    host: 'my.database-server.com',
    port: 5334,
    user: 'database-user',
    password: 'secretpassword!!',
  },
};
export const getActiveUsersLast7DaysForProject = async (projectId: string): Promise<string[]> => {
  let userIds: string[] = [];
  const client = new PG.Client(config.encryptedCredentials);
  await client.connect();

  await client
    .query(
      `
      SELECT user_id FROM my_db.users_active ua
      WHERE ua.project_id='12345'
      GROUP BY user_id`,
    )
    .then((res: any) => (userIds = res.rows.flatMap((user: any) => user.user_id)))
    .catch((e: Error) => console.error(e.stack));

  return userIds;
};
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { getActiveUsersLast7DaysForProject } from './';
import PG, { Client } from 'pg';

describe('69830430', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mClient: jasmine.SpyObj<Client> = jasmine.createSpyObj('client', ['connect', 'query']);
    mClient.query.and.resolveTo({ rows: [{ user_id: '1' }, { user_id: '2' }] });
    spyOn(PG, 'Client').and.returnValue(mClient);
    const actual = await getActiveUsersLast7DaysForProject('1');
    expect(actual).toEqual(['1', '2']);
    expect(mClient.connect).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(mClient.query).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
Executing 1 defined specs...
Running in random order... (seed: 89766)

Test Suites & Specs:

1. 69830430
   ✔ should pass (6ms)

>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  1 of 1
Specs:   1 of 1
Expects: 3 (0 failures)
Finished in 0.013 seconds
```